# How to wait for the promise when using get in Firestore

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, actions-on-google

I am just trying a simple get command with Firestore, using this code from Google it doesn't work because it's not waiting for the promise?

Earlier I had put only a snippet of code, this is the entirety of index.js -- I'm using Firestore with Dialogflow to build a Google Assistant app and trying to call a function from the welcome intent that gets a field from Firestore, then writes that field to a string (named question1), and then this string should be spoken by the assistant as part of the ssml response.  I've been on this for at least 30 hours already, can't seem to comprehend promises in regards to intents, firestore, etc. I've tried about 10 different solutions, this one works, only it says "undefined" in other variations I have tried it would say undefined several times but after 2-3 passes the get command would be complete and then the variable would be read out.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get the get command and variable set before moving onto the SSML response.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
      'use strict';


const functions = require('firebase-functions'); //don't forget this one

// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();
const collectionRef = db.collection('text');

const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

var doc;

var question1;

const url = require('url');
const {
dialogflow,
Image,
Permission,
NewSurface,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const {ssml} = require('./util');

const config = functions.config();

const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent';


const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

async function dbaccess(rando) {


console.log("dbaseaccess started")


var currentquestion2 = 'question-' + rando.toString();

var cityRef
try { return cityRef = db.collection('text').doc(currentquestion2).get();
console.log("get command completed")
//do stuff

question1 = cityRef.data().n111




} catch(e) {

//error!
}
console.log("one line above return something");

return rando;


}


app.fallback((conv) => {
// intent contains the name of the intent
// you defined in the Intents area of Dialogflow
const intent = conv.intent;






switch (intent) {
 case WELCOME_INTENT:

var rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
dbaccess(rando);




const ssml =
'<speak>' +
question1 +
'</speak>';
conv.ask(ssml);

break;


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `db.collection('cities').doc('SF')` returns the promise?

Comment: I believe you've asked this question before.  You're going to have to edit the question to go into more detail about what doesn't work the way you expect.  If you're writing code for actions on google, you'll need to provide the full context of what you're trying to achieve.  You're also going to have to learn how to deal with promises in javascript if you want to write effective code.

Comment: I've added the code above, I want the get command to assign a value to the string "question1" for use in the intent to be spoken by the app.

I've tried the recommendations here but I still get "undefined" for "question1" at least on the first couple passes, then eventually it does get a value (a text string) and the app can speak that string, but it doesn't do it reliably to always get the promise/get the value and not come back as undefined.

Comment: "I want the get command to assign a value to the string 'question1' for use in the intent to be spoken by the app." No, don't get sucked into using an outer variable. Get promises to work for you by having `dbaccess()` return a promise which resolves to `cityRef.data().n111`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options: you can use `async/await` or you can use `Promise.then()` depending on how you want the code to execute.

Async/await:

```
async function databasetest {
  var cityRef;
  try{
    cityRef = await db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
    // do stuff
  } catch(e) {
    // error!
  }
```

Promise.then():

```
db.collection('cities').doc('SF').then((cityRef) => {
  cityRef.get()
    .then(doc => { /* do stuff */ })
    .catch(err => { /* error! */ });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I believe this works not sure if it works for my implementation but this does return a promise.

My last test took 9 seconds to complete, this means this is not a viable way to start off a welcome message (by first retrieving some data) are there any workarounds?

Comment: I would have a static welcome message that doesn't require a database lookup, and load the database in the background.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little of work around could help you, I'm not sure yet how you are trying to implement it.

```
 function databasetest () {
  var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
  return cityRef.get()
  }

// so you can implement it like

databasetest().then(doc => {
 if (!doc.exists) {
   console.log('No such document!');
 } else {
   console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
 }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('Error getting document', err);
});
```

More context would help to understand your use case better :)

Comment: I tried that but got an error "Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?"

Is it possible to call a function inside an intent and then use the value from the function in the <speak> command?

Comment: would u mind to share your implementation? its really hard to tell without context

Comment: I just added everything in the code example, I'm using switch case to choose intents.  Those are all declared at the start and it does work (when I don't use the database).

You see when it triggers welcome intent it should call the function then get a value for question1, then the welcome intent can use that value in the <speak> command.

var question1 is also declared at the start. Like I said, it works normally (unless I start using Firestore).